# How to print using awk in UNIX the text from many files in different ways (by the file name position in argc)?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

This is what i have to do:
Display the content of the files given as arguments as follows: the
files on the positions 1, 3, 5, ... will be displayed normally.  The
files on the positions 2, 4, 6, ... print each line with the words in
revers order (last word is displayed first, next to last is displayed
second, etc).

I tryed in many ways but i can't figure out how to verify the position of the filename in the awk arguments list.

```
if(j%2!=0){
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            print $i
       }
else
    for(i=NF;i=1;i--)
            print $i
    }
```

This is how i can print the lines from a file.

```
BEGIN{
 for(j=1;j<ARGC;j++)
    a[j]=j
}
```

Here i tried to make a list with the number of arguments.

But how can i use the list with the if? Or how can i do this in a different way?

```
$ awk -f 2.awk 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

This is the command i used, where 2.awk is the source file.

Text file example:
    1.txt

```
1 2 3 4

a b c b
```

Comment: Can you give some examples for the text files?  I think you should be able to make a couple of associative arrays of the filenames in the BEGIN and then test FILENAME in the array you want to perform the output in the main block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you can massage this to your needs.  Heres an awk executable file that you would run like:

```
awkex 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

The contents of the executable awkex file are:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    for( i = 1; i < ARGC; i++ )
        {
        if( i % 2 == 0 ) { even_args[ ARGV[ i ] ] = ARGV[ i ]; }
        else { odd_args[ ARGV[ i ] ] = ARGV[ i ]; }
        }
    }
{
    if( odd_args[ FILENAME ] != "" )
        {
        for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
            printf( "%s ", $i );
        printf( "\n" );
        }
    else
        {
        for( j = NF; j > 0; j-- )
            printf( "%s ", $j );
        printf( "\n" );
        }
}
' $*
```

It's assuming every arg is a filename.  The odd ones got into one map, the evens into another map.  If the currently handled FILENAME is in the odd array, do one thing, else do the other.  It's also assuming the default separator.  You could change that with the -F flag in the "awkex" file.

Comment: Thx man... this is really helpfull... i'm just a beginner and i tried and studied about 3 hours for this program and it was impossible for me.   But, if i don't ask too  much, can you explain me please the first part? the BEGIN i mean

Comment: Sure.  The loop in the begin starts at the arg past zero "awkex" in this case and goes until the end of the args (ARGC) ( supplied by the `$*` from the shell ).  If a number is evenly divisible by 2, it puts it into the even_ags associative array ( really a map ) where the value is the same as the key.  It should work if you change the right side value to "monkey" or "1" etc ( but not "" ).  The odd_args get everything else.  What we really want is a hashset, but I don't think awk has those, so I just mirrored the key with the value.

Comment: the above should produce reasonable output but the trailing semi-colons have no function, the way to check for an index being in an array is via the "in" operator, printf is a builtin not a function, there's no need to loop through the fields to print them as-is ...

Comment: @Ed Morton heh - semi colons are a force of habit from the other languages I program in and long awk 'one liners'.  I didn't even notice them.  It's true that `if( FILENAME in odd_args ) print $0` would be cleaner than the first test/if loop I originally used.  My solution also leaves a trailing " " on the last element printed which is probably undesired.  Your solution's loop fixes the trailing space problem and is obviously more compact.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for ARGIND:

```
gawk '!(ARGIND%2){for (i=NF;i>1;i--) printf "%s ",$i; print $1; next} 1' file1 file2 ...
```

with other awks, just create your own "ARGIND" by incrementing a variable in an FNR==1 block, assuming none of the files are empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect time to use the FNR variable. If FNR==1 then you're at the first line of a file:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 {filenum++} 
    filenum%2==0 {
        # reverse the words of this line
        n = NF
        for (i=n; i>=1; i--) $(NF+1) = $i
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) $i = $(n+i)
        NF = n
    } 
    1
' one two three four five six
```

Testing:

```
# here's the contents of my files:
$ for f in one two three four five six ; do printf "%s: %s\n" $f "$(<$f)"; done
one: words in file one
two: words in file two
three: words in file three
four: words in file four
five: words in file five
six: words in file six

$ awk '                           
    FNR==1 {filenum++} 
    filenum%2==0 {
        n = NF
        for (i=n; i>=1; i--) $(NF+1) = $i
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) $i = $(n+i)
        NF = n
    } 
    1
' one two three four five six
```

outputs

```
words in file one
two file in words
words in file three
four file in words
words in file five
six file in words
```